Confusion with the proof for the Halting Problem
I was considering the halting problem, and I'm confused about why it is impossible.
As I understand it, the problem is defined as follows.
There exists a program $h(x,i)$ which takes as input a program $x$ and an input to that program $i$ and then reports if the program $x$ reaches a final decision on that input or if the program loops infinitely, returning true and false respectively.
Then, use $h$ to produce another program, $h'(x,i)$, which passes the arguments to $h$ and, if it reports true, goes into an infinite loop or halts if it reports false.
You then attempt to compute $h'(h',h')$.
Now the accepted logic is that this is a paradox; to label these options consider $h'_1(h'_2,h'_3)$

if $h'_2$ halts on $h'_3$, then $h'_1$ loops infinitely
if $h'_2$ does not halt on $h'_3$, then $h'_1$ reports true.

since $h'_1$ is actually the same as $h'_2$. the two results must be equal, but because the output of one is the inverse of the other, that can't be true. So, the problem is unsolvable.
But this struck me as a bit weird since you need to pass two things as an input to $h'_2$.
To break out the logic some more:

$h'_1$ receives two inputs, $h'_2$ $h'_3$
$h'_1$ feeds $h'_2$ and $h'3$ into $h$
$h$ attempts to calculate if $h'_2$ will halt on $h'3$
This fails because the input to $h'_2$ needs two parts

the program $x$ (which in this case is $h'_3$)
and the input to the program $x$ (which is missing)


The entire calculation runs headfirst into a wall because $h'_3$ receives an invalid input.

To break it down further, the $h$ instance in $h'_2$ does not receive the input to compare $h'_3$ against.



We defined that at the beginning, $h(x,i)$ can answer if program $x$ halts given input $i$. However, when we look at this calculation, we do not give $h'$ a valid input below the top level.
Now, it's been some time since I was exposed to the halting problem in an academic setting, but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

If you're familiar with the register machine approach to computability, you should be aware, that it is possible to omit the last argument. That is, given the registers that your machine operates on, it is possible to set only a subset of them manually, and then set the rest to 0.
The proof I know for the halting problem uses exactly this to avoid the problem you're running into.

@blomp But won't that mean the program is explicitly empty, so the contradiction doesn't work because $h'(h')$ is different from $h'(h', h')$? In other words, $h'$ evaluated on empty input runs forever, therefore $h'(h')$ halts, therefore $h'(h', h')$ runs forever without any issue since these are all separate inputs to $h'$?

To answer this part of the question:

However, when we look at this calculation, we do not give $h'$ a valid input below the top level.

(I hope my understanding is correct) We actually do pass it the correct input. $h'$ takes in a program and its input to determine its halting on that input. So when we take the program code of $h'$, its input is going to be the program we test it on, i.e. testing it on itself.
Note that $h' \neq h'(x,i)$, $h'$ represents the program code (in this context), while the latter represents the machine executing the code, and the machine actually needs the inputs, not the program itself (kind of paradoxical). So the machine gets the correct input, which is the program $h'$ itself and the input to the program, which is again going to be the program $h'$ since we are testing if $h'$ knows when $h'$ is going to halt.
The rest of the reasoning you did is correct.

That does clarify some things, but doesn't seem to answer the impossibility. if we assume that $h'(h',h')$ means that we are testing $h'(x,i)$ with the code of $h'$ using the code of $h'$ as an input condition, it still doesn't say why it can't find why the code is undecidable.
Actually, it still doesn't explain the correct input thing - $h(x,i)$ presumably still needs a valid input to $h'$ to evaluate the code as described initially.
Or does attempting to resolve an infinite loop count as a failure here?

Aha, so to clarify the impossibility. If we assume, as you mentioned, $h'(h', h')$ what does that actually mean? Well, $h'$ will simulate the program given, on the provided input, and if it determines that it will halt, it will loop, otherwise it will halt.
Now, let us analyse this. $h'$ will have to determine its behaviour, given itself as the input (both as program and input). The program represents the machine that will determine if a program halts so basically $h'$ and which program does it have to determine? Well, itself, therefore $h'(h',h')$.

If $h'$ (the machine) determines that $h'$ (the input) will halt, then the input also loops. But if the input loops, then $h'$ (the machine will halt). If $h'$ (the machine) determines that $h'$ (input) will not halt, then it will itself halt (same logic as above).
And that is the contradiction because $h'$ (the machine) always gives the exact opposite output as to what actually happens to $h'$ (the input), so the conclusion is that a program can not determine when it will halt, therefore it is impossible to know for sure - in general - whether a program halts at a given input or not.

@VanjaStojanović I don't think your reasoning works, because $h'$ with no input does not have to have the same halting behavior as $h'$ with itself as input. The problem is that Emizaquel constructed $h'$ incorrectly, see his answer for the correction.

Completely missed that *facepalm*, thanks for the oversight!

So, someone managed to explain it to me.
$h'(x)$ is a function that takes an input $x$, runs the function $h(x,x)$, and then halts or loops infinitely as stated, and $h'$ is the code for that function.
This means that $h'(h')$ is a valid configuration, since it would translate to $h(h',h')$ then do the opposite.
this then means that the $h'(h')$ would be a proper paradox, since the inputs are valid and produce a proper contradiction as $h(h',h')$ is checking for the halting of $h'$ given the input $h'$ which is identical to our starting point.
The result of $h'(h')$ would be properly inverted and thus incalculable.
